# Does is make sense to first check in the database if an entity exists before deletion using e.g. Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

For example, in Spring/SpringBoot you can use Spring Data JPA for adding and deleting data in the database.

Does it make sense before deleting an entity to first check if the entity exists? What are the advantages or disadvantages of doing so?

Answer (score 7):

In general it is a bad idea to check first before doing something e.g., check whether a file exists before opening it, or in this case, check whether a record in a database exists before deleting it. Most if not all systems are multi-threaded, multi-user systems, and just because a file existed a millisecond ago doesn't mean it will still exist when you try to open it, and just because a row in a table existed a millisecond ago doesn't mean it will still exist when you try to delete it.

For instance, it is possible that some other process or thread was in the middle of deleting it when you checked and was just about to commit the transaction. You check for the row; you see it exists. The transaction gets committed. You try to delete it, but it fails because there is no such row.

No amount of checking in advance can avoid a failure. Because of this, you always have to handle the case where failure occurs. So it is always better to simply try the operation and handle the case where it fails.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spring Data and delete a non-exist Entity using deleteById(), you will get an Exception. 
So if better to handle this exception in your code.

```
@Transactional
public void deleteById(ID id) {
    Assert.notNull(id, "The given id must not be null!");
    this.delete(this.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> {
        return new EmptyResultDataAccessException(String.format("No %s entity with id %s exists!", this.entityInformation.getJavaType(), id), 1);
    }));
}
```

You can avoid this by rewriting the query

```
@Modifying
@Query(nativeQuery =true, value = "DELETE from reservation r WHERE r.id = ?1")
void deleteById(Long id);
```

Also, no exception thrown if you use derived methods,such as

```
void deleteByReservationNumber(String reservationNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the use case. I think the only main disadvantage for doing so is one extra database access, which always costs way more than RAM access.

Spring hibernate JPA will already throw an `EmptyResultDataAccessException` if you try to delete something that does not exist, so you can do this:

```
try {
      repository.deleteById(id);
} catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
      // some log or business logic here
}
```

`Warning:` for example, if you use MongoDB, Spring hibernate will not throw an exception, so if you really want to know if the record exists before deletion you have to explicit check it (costing an extra DB access).

Answer (score 0):

Spring will throw an error for the built in functionality for deleting if the entity doesn't exist, but if you write a custom query it will no throw an error. It will also simplify your code.

in your repository you can have a query like this:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("DELETE from f FROM foo f WHERE f.id = ?1")
void deleteById(int Id);
```

This will take advantage of how the Database handles empty entities instead of Spring/Hibernate